# NavigationService doesn't have a definition

Tags: c#, wpf

I want a forward button in my MainWindow.xaml to navigatie in my history to the correct pages. This is what I added to my Backbutton click:

```
private void BackClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        {
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

The error that keeps being dispayed is

```
'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'NavigationService'
```

As far as I know my import are correct

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Comment: WPF's Window class does not have a `NavigationService` property, not sure where you got that idea from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
this.NavigationService
```

property does not exist in your `MainWindow` class. Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more information. You need to access the `NavigationService` from a `Frame`, `Page` or `NavigationWindow`.